# Launching an Android application from within app

Tags: java, android

To launch an Android application I use below code which works for fine for every application
installed on phone except for the "Phone" application itself. When I attempt to launch "Phone" the 
app is not launced and no error message or displayed or exception thrown.

This is the code I'm using to launch the application :

```
launchApp(context, packageManager,
"com.android.phone");

/*
 * Launch an application
 * 
 * @param c Context of application
 * 
 * @param pm the related package manager of the context
 * 
 * @param pkgName Name of the package to run
 */
public static boolean launchApp(Context c, PackageManager pm, String pkgName) {
    // query the intent for lauching
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
    // if intent is available
    if (intent != null) {
        try {
            // launch application
            c.startActivity(intent);
            // if succeed
            return true;

            // if fail
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // quick message notification
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, "Application Not Found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            // display message
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    // by default, fail to launch
    return false;
}
```

Is this the correct method to use for launching an Android application and/or is the "Phone"
app a special case which does not allow other applications to launch/use it ?

Comment: "Is the correct method to use for launcging an Android application" -- not really. Users launch activities, not applications. Home screen launchers do not use your technique, but instead find and show all `HOME`/`LAUNCHER` activities. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot

Comment: I think if do a query with MAIN / LAUNCHER you'll find the "phone" app anyway, in this case there is a little of confusion actually and the question is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: are you trying on a phone or on the emulator?

Comment: emulator, but I will try phone now

Comment: according to Android documentation the ACTION_DIAL without any input must do the work "Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is started", maybe it's a problem/bug of the android emulator image